# When is the "lock-in" point for the Diana Allers romance?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Generally, in Mass Effect, you're limited to monogamous romance.  However, Diana Allers seems (from what I've read) to be a little unique.

- The Mass Effect Wiki entry for [Diana Allers](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Diana_Allers#Romance) notes that she does not become a "committed partner".
- The Mass Effect Wiki entry on [Romance](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Romance#Romance_options_3) does not include a "lock in" point for the Diana Allers romance.

As it is now, I've done a bit of mostly harmless flirting with her up to (and including) the second interview - the one where she says she might follow me home like a lost puppy or something.  However, my end goal for this particular version of Commander Shepard is to be with Liara.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**  I'm not seeking to actually *romance* both characters - i.e.: reach the final love scene or establish a permanent relationship with both.  I've just been perhaps a little too friendly with one person than I should have, while I'm intending to pursue another.

Have I gone too far with Diana for me to have a successful romance with Liara, or is there actually no point of no return (besides the final romance scene) with Allers like there is with the others?

Comment: Okay, it's a dupe, but do you really need to downvote it?

Comment: It's not a dupe. Iszi wants to know where the point of no return is. The other question is kind of a yes/no type.

Comment: I boinked Diana first and afterwards started a romance with Ashley, which makes me presume there is no point of no return with Diana. It is just a fling ;)

Comment: @Lyrion then you should post that as an answer

Comment: @spartacus Ah but perhaps Ashley doesn't mind... there is no way to know for sure that the same will happen with Liara unless you try...

Comment: @Lyrion IIRC there are *some* psuedo-romance options (non-Paramour romances) that have a lock-in point which precludes the possibility of other romances while you're locked in, but still frees you up later after the romance is completed.  Your description of romancing Allers, then Williams, seems to fit that scheme - although it does not give us enough detail to determine whether there was a lock-in point along the way.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have managed to gather, the lock in point is the third interview scene. After this, other characters will consider her "locked in". As such, Liara and others will call you out if you pursue relationship with them after this scene.

However, she is not considered "full" romance option and as such does not give an achievement. There are also some weird things, with some characters noticing your relationship with her and others not. As such, her "lock in" point could be considered buggy.

Also, if you are already committed to another romance, you can't proceed with Allers. As such, concentrating on other will help you strafe off Allers.

Comment: are you sure you aren't confusing Allers with Traynor?  I thought the shower scene was with Traynor and not Allers.

Comment: Definitely some Allers/Traynor confusion here. As far as I know, there's not even a scene where Allers has her clothes off, let alone takes a shower.

Comment: Yeah. Got stuff mixed, been sometime since I played the game. Fixing stuff.